# Way to see # users currently viewing a question

Tags: feature-request

has it been discussed, or do you think it would be a *neat* feature, if we could see how many people (or who) are viewing a question at the time you load the page? (Similar to a chat room)

Currently we can see a sum(views), but what about how many users are actively on this page as of the time you loaded the page.

Comment: I can't think of any reasons I'd want/need to, but I am open to suggestions as to why it's a useful thing.

Comment: potentially related: [How many users are currently logged on?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19002/how-many-users-are-currently-logged-on), [Can we have a counter showing how many user are currently active?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14551/can-we-have-a-counter-showing-how-many-user-are-currently-active) (**declined**),

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [D]o you think it would be a *neat* feature[?]

Sorry, no. At least not the *who* part.

Voting is supposed to be anonymous. If you can see who's viewing a question right now, it won't be hard to deduce which vote is from whom.

The number of users currently viewing a question isn't interesting in my opinion. What means viewing? I can open the tab, leave it open and go for coffee. Am I *viewing* all the time, only the first five minutes or something else? In any way, the number won't display any relevant information.

A real-time update for the view count could prevent energic refreshing though.

Comment: Very good points....may I ask the reason for the [D] in your response :)

Comment: I'm being pedantic. You used a lowercase `D`, so the uppercase `D` doesn't form part of the quote.

Comment: Ahhhh I've always wondered why people did that...thanks! You can even learn grammar on SO haha

Comment: Is it good or bad that I'm upvoting your pedantic grammar comment? I'm still not sure.